# can we use database function with searchkick or elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, searchkick

let say I have a table users(id, name) and a database function say f1(user_id integer)

in psql, I can do 
`select id, name, f1(id) from users where f1(id) > 5 order by f1(id)`

can I use this function f1 somehow with searchkick or elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

You can save a field with the results of f1 to Elasticsearch.

```
class User
  def search_data
    {
      id: id,
      name: name,
      f1: self.class.select("f1(id)").find(id).f1
    }
  end
end
```

Then reindex and query with Searchkick.